# sed -e : is it possible to match everything between two quotation marks?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Sed, is it possible to match everything between two chars?

In a script that I have to use there is a bug.
The script has to replace the value of

`#define MAPPING`,

The line containing the bug is the one below:

```
sed -i -e "s/#define MAPPING \"\"/#define MAPPING \"$string\"/1" file.hpp
```

Since in `file.hpp` MAPPING is defined as:
`#define MAPPING ""`

the script works, but if I try to call the script again and MAPPING was already redefined, now `sed` won't match #define MAPPING "" and thus not override anything.

I'm not a sed expert, and with a quick search couldn't find the way to let it match
`#define MAPPING "<everything>"`.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think I understood your question well, but I think you are looking for `#define MAPPING \"[^\"]*\"` in the search section

Comment: You should test any potential solution after setting `string='foo&bar'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is does you want:

```
sed -Ei 's/(#define MAPPING ")[^"]*(")/\1'"$string\2/" file.hpp
```

- `[^"]*` means zero or more *non* double quote characters.
- I used back references instead of repeating the same text, it's up to you.
- `1` at the end of your example means replace the first occurence. However this is the default, so it can be removed.
- Be aware: if `$string` contains sequences like `&`, `\5`, or `\\`, they won't be passed literally, and can even cause an error. Also, C escapes like `\t` for tab are expanded by many sed implementations (so you'll end up with a literal tab in the file, instead of `\t`).

For what it's worth, this sed does the same thing, but is more accomodating of varied whitespace:

```
sed -Ei 's/(^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*define[[:space:]]+MAPPING[[:space:]]+")[^"]*(")/\1'"$string\2/" file.hpp
```

Comment: Matching and back referencing the spaces before the `#` has no use. Spaces between `#` and `define` might cause syntax errors: IMHO lines with spaces here should not be matched.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
sed -i -e "s/#define MAPPING \".*\"/#define MAPPING \"$string\"/1" file.hpp
```

The dot means anything can go here and the star means at least 0 times so `.*` accepts any sequence of characters, including an empty string.